# BigQuery check if a nested field exist

Tags: google-bigquery

In my dataset, we have a record field of key& value pairs. I want to get entries that having a key ="mykey" in the record. How should I do the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM t.your_repeated_record_field
  WHERE key ='mykey'
)
```

Comment: thank you @mikhail, I am trying to do a count `select count(*) from mytable`, and it returns 256.
but when I run `select count(*) from mytable`, it returns only one entry. I tried your query and the query with inner join unnest, when I did count, they returned 16, but when I select *, they just returned 1 entry. Could you please suggest?

Comment: not clear what exactly you ask to suggest! I answered your question as it is - the query in my answer should return only those rows in your table where there is a key ='mykey' - if it returns just one row - it most likely mean you have just one row with such key :o)

Comment: Mikhail Berlyant answer is correct according to your question. It would be great if you could re-formulate it and if possible, provide a data sample of your dataset in order to better understand your issue.